# Proving the inverse of the invertible matrix theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ invertible matrix and $v_1,v_2,...,v_m$ an element of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. If $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_m\}$ spans $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ then $\{Av_1, Av_2,...,Av_m\}$ also spans $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

How to prove that if $A$ is not invertible, then $\{Av_1, Av_2,...,Av_m\}$ does not span $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ is not invertible. Then, I claim $A$ is not surjective, by contradiction.

Suppose that $A$ were surjective. By the rank nullity theorem, $\dim \mathbb{R}^n = \dim \ker A + \dim \text{im} A$. Since $\dim \text{im} A  =n$ by surjectivity, it follows that $\dim \ker A = 0\implies \ker A = \{ 0\}$, so $A$  is injective, hence invertible, which is a contradiction. Hence, we are done.

Comment: @user218931 Oh, I totally forgot about that! Well,editing time! Okay, editing done!